# Simplification for a double summation where the upper limit of the inner index depends on the value of the outer index?

Tags: summation

$$\sum_{x=1}^{N} \sum_{y=1}^{M(x)} (1 + a\cdot f\left(x\right))(1 + b \cdot f\left(y\right)) \tag{1}$$

where $N$, $a$, and $b$ are integer constants. $M$ is also an integer but changes for every value of x, which makes the index of the second summation dependent on the first. The problem is the relationship $M(x)$ is analytically difficult to define. Is there a way to simplify this expression?

Comment: +1 for such an interesting question!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would evaluate this expression in the following way (in order):

1. Select the $x$ value (starting with $x=1$)
2. Then evaluate $M(x)$
3. Now you have a sum of the form, where now we have $M\equiv M(x),f\equiv f(x)$:

$$\tag{1}
\sum_{y=1}^{M} \left(1 + a\cdot f\right)(1 + b \cdot f\left(y\right))
$$

4. Proceed to the next value of $x$ (in this case it's $x=2$)
5. Go back to Step 2, 3, and 4, where the $M$ and $f$ can be slightly different (depending on the new value of $x$) from what you had before.

I'm certain that there's no way to "simplify" your expression without knowing the functional form of $M(x)$, for example is it $M(x)=\cos(x)$ or is it $M(x)=x^2 - \log(x) + \max(x,y,f(x),f(y),f(x)-f(y))$?

Comment: Yup, I expanded the inner summation first: $\displaystyle \begin{aligned} \sum_{x=1}^N \sum_{y=1}^{M(x)} (1+af(x))(1+bf(y)) & =  \sum_{x=1}^N \sum_{y=1}^{M(x)} 1 + af(x) + bf(y) + abf(x)f(y) \\[0.3cm] & = \sum_{x=1}^N \bigg[ M(x)[1+ af(x)] \bigg] + b \sum_{x=1}^N \bigg[ [1 + af(x)] \sum_{y=1}^{M(x)} f(y) \bigg]\end{aligned}$

Comment: Well done !!!!! But you'd still have to use the procedure in my answer to take care of the $b$ term in your last expression.

Comment: Yup, for loop all the way ! Thank you for your help and the edits.

Answer (score -1):

Not sure what you are looking for but you can change the order of integration as long as you include all cells in the yellow triangle.  For instance,

$\sum_{y=1}^{N} \sum_{x = M^{-1}(y)}^N (1 + a f(x))(1 + b(f(y))$

is the same.

[If $M(x) = x$, the sum is over the yellow trangular region](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n1gnu.png)

You can also expand the product

$\sum_{x=1}^{N} \sum_{y = 1}^{M(x)} (1 + a f(x))(1 + b(f(y)) = \sum_{x=1}^{N} \sum_{y = 1}^{M(x)} 1 + a f(x) + bf(y) + abf(x)f(y)$